# Cannot find name 'Exclude'. Apollo, Graphql

Tags: graphql, angular6, apollo

Hi guys I have a problem. I'm trying to include Apollo in my Angular 6 project and when i want to run my application I'm facing an issue. I receive this error.

```
ERROR in node_modules/apollo-angular/types.d.ts(10,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
```

In lib from tsconfig.json I have :

```
 "lib": [
  "esnext.asynciterable",
  "es2017",
  "dom",
]
```

But I still receive this error. What I can change to be able to run my app?

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same issue, but used another approach (hack). apollo-angular seems to be using a type "Exclude" that is not available to Angular 6 in the tsconfig.json options, so adding an "es5"  as following will do the trick:

`"lib": [
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "es5",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
    ]`

If that doesn't work, you can declare this type in the  node_modules/apollo-angular/types.d.ts file directly as:

`declare type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;`

This last option is a hack and will be overwritten by any "npm install" or apollo-angular updates, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and solve it by running the following cmd command:

> npm install typescript@2.9.2 --save-exact

Answer (score 0):

so I updated typescript version to 2.8.1 and now it work. The thing is now i receive a warning from angular because angular expect to have version < 2.8.0 but it's just a warning and i can hide that.